# $S^3$ as a Sasakian Manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, contact-geometry, sasakian-geometry

Reading about Sasakian manifolds one come across two slogans:

A) "A Sasakian manifold is an odd-dimensional analogue of a Kahler manifold."

B) "A Sasakian manifold sits between two Kahler manifolds - one above and one below."

I would like to understand the second slogan for the motivating example 
of the three sphere $S^3$. What are the two Kahler manifolds that it sits 
between? I would guess that below is the projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$. But 
I cannot guess what lies above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer your question for $S^{2n+1}$, since there is no difference between the case $n=1$ and the case of general $n$.

Let $(M^{2n+1},g,\theta)$ be a Sasakian manifold.  One definition of a Sasakian manifold is that its metric cone is Kähler; this is the "one above".  Here the *metric cone* is the manifold $M\times(0,\infty)$ with metric $dt^2+t^2g$.  Thus in the case of $S^{2n+1}$, the metric cone is $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ with the flat metric (written in spherical coordinates).

Taking the quotient by the $S^1$-action on $(M^{2n+1},\theta)$ determined by the Reeb vector field gives the "Kähler manifold below".  For $S^{2n+1}$, the $S^1$-action is scalar multiplication by $e^{i\phi}$ (regarding $S^{2n+1}$ as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$), so the quotient is $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

Comment: Will the metric cone be non-compact in general?

Comment: Does this not work for n =0? S1 x R does not seem to be homeomorphic to C.

Comment: @Asvin I think it should be $[0,\infty)$, with $M \times 0$ quotiented out. This part goes to the origin.

Comment: I see. That makes more sense, thanks!

Comment: The usual definition does not include $0$ in the second factor, the reason being that $(M\times[0,\infty)/\sim,dt^2+t^2g)$ is not smooth at the origin unless $M$ is a round sphere (here $\sim$ identifies $M\times\{0\}$ to a point).  I have edited the original answer to reflect that the origin is missing.  Also, the metric cone is always noncompact, because of the second factor.